# ¿Dónde encuentro versiones anteriores de Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: linux, jasper, jaspersoft

estoy necesitando la versión 6.20.1 de jaspersoft studio, sin embargo no encuentro de donde descargar el instalador para Linux.

Si alguien me podría dar información al respecto.
De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.